# How to inject a Windows API call use ollydbg in Windows7 x64

Tags: windows, debugging, process, cracking, ollydbg

I am using Windows7 x64, and OllyDbg 2.01(alpha 2)

I have an exe, and I want to popup a MessageBox to show some information during execution, and there is a great tutorial shows you how to do this:  [How to inject code into a exe file](http://home.inf.fh-rhein-sieg.de/~ikarim2s/how2injectcode/code_inject.html), basically, it is about adding a MessageBoxA API call with the wanted information:

```
PUSH 0                 ; BUTTONS = <OK ONLY>
PUSH 1008751           ; CAPTION  = Our adress of the "INJECTED NOTEPAD"
PUSH 1008751           ; MESSAGE  = Same like above.
PUSH 0                 ; ICON        = <NO ICON>
CALL MessageBoxA       ; Run MessageBoxA with the Params above.
```

It does work when in live debug session: I injected the code, and then debug it - the message box does pops up. But after I save the executable
(RMB->Edit->Select all; RMB->Edit->Copy to executable; In the new window, RMB->save file), and then execute, it just crashed.

Here are what I've observed:

> Before save, the CALL MessageBoxA is actually CALL 74DAFD1E, which
>   means 74DAFD1E is the address of API MessageBoxA, but after save, the
>   address is changed to some other value.

Also, do you think [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) would virtually stop up from injecting windows API call?

Any ideas? how could I managed to show the information I wanted from that exe?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, most likely ASLR is killing you here, because the address of `MessageBoxA` is fixed-up at load time. An easy hack would be to find another spot in the EXE where `MessageBoxA` is called, and copy the `call __` code it uses. Most likely it will be a call to a stub that is fixed up.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that, it is calling something like: CALL DWORD PTR DS:[<&USER32.MessageBoxA>], but when I inject this code at my spot, it simply transform to a fixed address, which will fail

Comment: No, you need to look at the static executable. Try [IDA](http://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/index.shtml). They have a free version.  Or, use a hex editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by ASLR, to make it work in Windows7, one approach is to disable ASLR (at your own risk).

You can download the [Enhanced Mitigation Experience Toolkit (EMET)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2458544) tool, install and run EMET_GUI.exe, in the pop up dialog, disable the ASLR and reboot:
[image: EMET GUI]

You may want to re-enable ASLR after finishing your work, as it has impact on your OS's security.